# get text after the _ in a string

Tags: php

basically i just want to get all the text after the _ .

i have tried

```
$productid = split("_",$PagePath, 1);
```

with no success what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explode instead of split. The result of explode is an array, so use `list()`:

```
list(,$productid) = explode('_', $PagePath, 2);
```

Note the third parameter, 2 instead of 1. Using 1 will not split anything. Or, just use `preg_replace`:

```
$productid = preg_replace('/^.*?_/', '', $PagePath);
```

Comment: Thank you :D did the job perfectly, how the hell did i forget about regex god its too late

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
$productidtokens = explode("_",$pagePath, 2);
if(count($productidtokens)>1)
  $productid = $productidtokens[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

$productId = substr($string, (strpos($PagePath, '_') + 1)); //+1 accounts for the underscore

Answer (score 0):

Try `$productid = explode('_',$PagePath)`.

If you just intended to take the text after the '_', then get rid the first index in the array created by write : `array_shift($productid)`.